# after fetch, my website data always reloading. so search function does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, use-effect

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [displayProduct, setDisplayProduct] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/products')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setProducts(data)
                setDisplayProduct(data)
                console.log(data);
            })
    })

    const handleSearch = (e) => {
        const searchText = e.target.value;
        const matchedProduct = products?.filter((data) =>
            data.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchText?.toLowerCase())
        );
        setDisplayProduct(matchedProduct);
        console.log(searchText);
        console.log(matchedProduct);

    };
    console.log(products);[here you can see always increasing ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOeaM.png
```

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the api again and again after making change in your state ,as `useEffect` is called as an sideEffect after every state change ,so it creates an infinite loop

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/products')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                setProducts(data)
                setDisplayProduct(data)
                console.log(data);
            })
    },[])
```

Pass an empty array in the `useEffect`.It will call the useEffect only once when your page loads for the first time

See this answer -[React Hooks - 0 vs. empty array as second argument in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62781907/react-hooks-0-vs-empty-array-as-second-argument-in-useeffect)